# How to append a column to a 2d vector in modern C++

Tags: c++

I am thinking about what's the modern way to append a column to a 2d vector.
I have attempted the following approaches:
1. Naive way:

```
void insert_col(vector<vector<int>>& data, vector<int>& newCol){
    if(newCol.size()!=data.size()){
        return ;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
        data[i].push_back(newCol[i]);
    }
}
```

Second attempt that does not work:

```
transform(data.begin(), data.end(), newCol.begin(), /*not sure about this part*/, [](vector<int>& row, int colVale)->int{return colVale;});
```

The idea is to use transform to iterate both 2d vector and the column to be inserted. I am wondering if there's a way to append at the end of each row?

3. Third attempt:

   reinsert each row into the data.begin() which would work but probably not efficient.

   Any other efficient solution would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about a library like `Eigen` or `MKL`?

Answer (score 2):

You ask for an efficient solution.  But you have hobbled performance from the outset by using a naive `vector<vector<int>>` and storing the data row-wise when you want to append column-wise.

Rectangular matrices are better stored in a single vector with fancy indexing (e.g. `data.get(i, j)` instead of `data[i][j]`).  If you store column-wise, appending a column is as simple as:

```
data.push_back(newCol);
```

Comment: But if you store it in a single vector I assume it would be inefficient when you try to insert or delete rows?

Comment: @Rockingchief: One or the other is going to be inefficient: either inserting columns or inserting rows.  Or you'll make those two things efficient and have inefficiency elsewhere.  You need to nail down what your use cases are.  In any case, the original code is not efficient at all, and making it more "modern" won't fix that.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
//For each vector<int> in the 2d vector, 
//push_back the corresponding element from the newCol vector
for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [&i, &newCol](vector<int>& v){v.push_back(newCol[i++]);});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do like this:

```
void insert_col(vector<vector<int>>& data, vector<int>& newCol) {
    data.push_back(newCol);
}
```